# Telegram bot uploaded media storage usage

Tags: optimization, random, bots, telegram

I have a bot which generates and sends random static sticker upon request. Since every image is completely random (over 4 trillion variations), there's no way to track if this variant was generated before and refer to the same file without re-uploading it.

Is it possible to check how much space does media uploaded by bot takes on Telegram servers and clean it up if it's too much, or the only solution is to set up a timer to delete file after some time? Official documentation seems to have no answer.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution for the problem, there's a [messages.getDocumentByHash](https://core.telegram.org/method/messages.getDocumentByHash) function. However, if there's a way to check total bot uploaded media size, please let me know.